# How to set metadata of a S3 object on serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

AWS s3 allows setting the metadata of a S3 object in the console as described on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html.

How can I configure that on the serverless.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It can be done with serverless-s3-sync. https://yingzuo.io/set-metadata-of-s3-objects-on-serverless-yml